# Transforming numbers in a matrix structure into color squares

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting

Suppose we have a matrix of numbers

$$\begin{matrix}
    1 & 3 & 2 & 4 \\ 
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\    
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\   \end{matrix}$$

I would like to transform in MathJax a matrix of numbers into the matrix where entries are color squares. The example of this could be the text **below**    (visible as the final effect)

$$\begin{matrix}
    \color{red}\blacksquare \color{teal}\blacksquare \color{#0F0}\blacksquare \color{blue}\blacksquare \\   
    \color{red}\blacksquare \color{#0F0}\blacksquare \color{teal}\blacksquare \color{blue}\blacksquare \\     
    \color{red}\blacksquare \color{#0F0}\blacksquare \color{teal}\blacksquare \color{blue}\blacksquare \\  \end{matrix}$$

however it has a drawback that it has inserted vertical and horizontal spaces between squares.   Mapping between integer numbers and colors is fixed.

- How to do it without additional spacing? (to obtain continuous
  rectangular color area - at least to remove spacing between lines)

The solution is possible in Latex, but how to obtain similar result only in MathJAx?

Comment: This seems (to some extent) related: [Does MathJaX have a command to stretch or reduce vertical space?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13649/does-mathjax-have-a-command-to-stretch-or-reduce-vertical-space)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thank you Martin for the link, for sure these propositions are useful in many situations. However in my problem I have tried the proposed solutions  and I don't see significant effect..

Comment: There are a few CSS-type annotations that are possible to specify in mathjax. But these are aimed at the website owners (who choose which configuration to load) instead of at us users. I suppose it would be possible to load your own mathjax if you wanted...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it, but you need to use large squares and hide their height and depth using `\smash`.  It helps to use a definition or two.  Here is one approach:

```
\def\smallstrut{\Space{0em}{.6em}{.2em}}
\def\cbox#1{\textstyle\smash{\color{#1}{\Rule{1em}{.8em}{.2em}}}\smallstrut}
\begin{smallmatrix}
\cbox{red}\cbox{teal}\cbox{green}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{green}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{green}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{green}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\end{smallmatrix}
```

which produces:

$$
\def\smallstrut{\Space{0em}{.6em}{.2em}}
\def\cbox#1{\textstyle\smash{\color{#1}{\Rule{1em}{.8em}{.2em}}}\smallstrut}
\begin{smallmatrix}
\cbox{red}\cbox{teal}\cbox{#0F0}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{#0F0}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{#0F0}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{#0F0}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\end{smallmatrix}
$$

If you want a small amount of space between the rows and columns, you can change the size of the `\smallstrut` and add a little width to it

```
\def\smallstrut{\Space{.2em}{.8em}{.2em}}
```

with the rest being the same:

$$
\def\smallstrut{\Space{.2em}{.8em}{.2em}}
\def\cbox#1{\textstyle\smash{\color{#1}{\Rule{1em}{.8em}{.2em}}}\smallstrut}
\begin{smallmatrix}
\cbox{red}\cbox{teal}\cbox{#0F0}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{#0F0}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{#0F0}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\cbox{red}\cbox{#0F0}\cbox{teal}\cbox{blue}\\
\end{smallmatrix}
$$

Comment: Excellent answer!  The method can be very useful in graphical presenting matrices. Thank you.